# Persisting sshd_config settings

Tags: ssh, configuration, sshd, etc

When modifying Linux configuration files, it is often recommended to place local changes under a `.d` directory, e.g., `/etc/sudoers.d/` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. In my understanding this is to avoid system updates overwriting the local changes if they were directly placed to files such as `/etc/sudoers` or `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Is there a similar way to apply local `sshd_config` settings? Currently, I am direclty modifying the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, but I am worried that I may lose all the changes after some update replacing that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not by default. However there are many alternative solutions. You can make sshd look for the configuration elsewhere, or keep a backup of the configuration.

You can also 'chattr +i' your configuration as root to prevent editing/removal by any user as long as the immutable flag is set.